# Testing for a true, and a false condition in modernizr.load

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I have 3 test conditions for Modernizr.load.

- If A is false, I load A.js
- If B is false, I load B.js
- If both A and B are true, and C is false, I load C.js

Currently if A, B, and C are all false, then they are all loaded, whereas I only want A and B to be loaded.

How can I test for both true and false conditions in the same "test:"?

My code looks like:

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: Modernizr.A,
        nope: 'A.js'
    },
    {
        test: Modernizr.B,
        nope: 'B.js'
    },
    {
        test: !Modernizr.A && !Modernizr.B && Modernizr.C,
        nope: 'C.js'
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this like so:

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: Modernizr.A,
        nope: 'A.js'
    },
    {
        test: Modernizr.B,
        nope: 'B.js',
        complete: function() {
            if ( Modernizr.A && Modernizr.B ){
                Modernizr.load({
                    test: Modernizr.C,
                    nope: 'C.js'
                });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```